# npm with compilation process sass cammand line

Tags: css, node.js, sass, command-line, compilation

i have problem with compile  process  sass with command line ,I use npm.js , i am trying to learn scss .

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is the problem bellow the code of file **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "yes",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "guitar website",
  "main": " ",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "server": "live-server --browser=chrome",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel server sass"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

the terminal show this error :

```
    User@DESKTOP-JKP464G MINGW64 ~/Desktop/learn with elzero/template 3 html scss
$ npm run start

> yes@1.0.0 start C:\Users\User\Desktop\learn with elzero\template 3 html scss
> npm-run-all --parallel server sass


> yes@1.0.0 server C:\Users\User\Desktop\learn with elzero\template 3 html scss
> live-server --browser=chrome


> yes@1.0.0 sass C:\Users\User\Desktop\learn with elzero\template 3 html scss
> node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w

'live-server' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an executable program or a batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! yes@1.0.0 server: `live-server --browser=chrome`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the yes@1.0.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-23T16_02_37_907Z-debug.log 
ERROR: "server" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! yes@1.0.0 start: `npm-run-all --parallel server sass`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the yes@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-23T16_02_38_125Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error is in French. Since [StackOverflow is an English-language resource](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/), without a translation a majority of users cannot help or benefit from content in another language.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have you node_modules folder, else you should do npm-install node-sass --save. Before running you scripts